# Add event handler to button from source view on an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a pretty complex html design of an aspx page on my proyect and neither the Design or the Split view show the complete list of controllers, because of that problem i need to add an event handler to a button just from the source view.

How i can add a event handler to a button just from the source view on c#?

Comment: `source view` Do you mean code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you can attach click event using `+=`.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SubmitButton.Click += SubmitButton_Click;
}

private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VB.Net, you can use the OnClick attribute or some other attribute basing on the required event you want to handle. Otherwise, you can always do it using the code-behind file and attach the event as suggested by Win.